# serverless.yml How to reference lambda function in Cognito Lambda Config

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, amazon-cognito

I am pretty new to serverless and I am trying to setup custom challenge for Cognito from serverless yaml file. I have following function

`functions:
  t-challenge-define:
    handler: t-auth-challenge.define
  t-challenge-create:
    handler: t-auth-challenge.create
  t-challenge-response:
    handler: t-auth-challenge.verifyResponse
resources:
  Resources:
        CognitoUserPool:
          Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
          Properties:
             UserPoolName: my_user_pool_name
             MfaConfiguration: "OFF"
             UsernameAttributes:
                - phone_number
             Schema:
                -   Name: phone_number
                    AttributeDataType: String
                    Mutable: false
                    Required: true
                -   Name: locale
                    AttributeDataType: String
                    Mutable: true
                    Required: true
             LambdaConfig:
                    DefineAuthChallenge: (how do i reference func here)`

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cognito-userpool-lambdaconfig.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
LambdaConfig:
 DefineAuthChallenge: "arn:aws:lambda:${self:custom.region}:${self:custom.accountId}:function:t-challenge-define"
```

you need to add arn with specific format as above.

Comment: `${self:custom.accountId}` You can't reference like that, unless you have added the `accountId` to your custom property.

Answer (score 5):

```
LambdaConfig:
      DefineAuthChallenge:
        Fn::GetAtt: [ T-challenge-defineLambdaFunction, Arn ]
      CreateAuthChallenge:
        Fn::GetAtt: [ T-challenge-createLambdaFunction, Arn ]
      VerifyAuthChallengeResponse:
        Fn::GetAtt: [ T-challenge-responseLambdaFunction, Arn ]
```

You can also leverage the GetAtt CloudFormation function to get the exact ARN for your lambda functions.